# How to decorate a segment of a filled path in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like the straight segment be a `zigzag` decoration:

[image]

Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass[tikz, preview=true]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=green] (1,1) to[out=45, in=140, bend left] (1,2) to[decorate, decoration=zigzag] (1.5,1.5) to[out=330, in=212, bend right] cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One solution here is to use a decoration 'scope':

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=green] 
     (1,1) to [out=45, in=140, bend left] (1,2)
     decorate [decoration={zigzag, segment length=3pt, amplitude=1pt}] 
     { to (1.5,1.5) } to [out=330, in=212, bend right] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]